# Making calculations with time using datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, python-datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to make simple calculations with time using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time = datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
endtime = time + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
print(type(endtime))
```

However, when i run the code i get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Also using just the following gives an error. I hope anyone knows the solution.

```
endtime = time + timedelta(minutes = 5)
```

Comment: Personally, I always use `import datetime as dt` to a) save on not having to type `datetime` all the time and b) to not get confused about whether `datetime` refers to the module or the class

Comment: Remove `.time()` and use `endtime = time + timedelta(minutes = 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) directly from [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

So you can just use it straight away:

```
endtime = time + timedelta(minutes = 5)
```

You also can't `+` increment a [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) object with `timedelta`, so you need to keep it as a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object by removing `.time()`:

```
 time = datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

**Working Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time = datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
endtime = time + timedelta(minutes = 5)
print(type(endtime))
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Another way you could have done this is with just importing `datetime` as a standard import:

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
endtime = time + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
print(type(endtime))
# # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

**Incremented time:**

```
print(endtime.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
# 12:05:00
```

Using [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).